# Batch variable being erased

Tags: batch-file

My code has in the first line you type '1' '2' '3' or '4'. Depending on what you type it will set a different variable. The problem is later in the code it leaves the variable blank like it erased it.

I have `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at the beginning of my code. I also tried with different capitalization and nothing happened.
Here is the part where the variable is set:

```
set /p choice=
if %choice% == 1 (
    goto title
    set mode= 10
)
```

I'm going to assume there is just something I didn't know was needed like the `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`. I tried searching here and on google but I couldn't word it very well.

Comment: Slightly related: `set mode= 10` will include a space at the start of the variable value. It is likely that you don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your SET before your GOTO.

Right now, the GOTO happens and execution never reaches the SET command.